# Association rule mining and Orange3 package Python

Tags: python

how i use Orange3 package for association rule mining ,in Orange 2.7 version Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer() method is present but its not available in Orange3 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Orange 3, `AssociationRulesSparseInducer` is removed.

The [documentation](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html) of Orange-Associate may help you on your task.

### References

https://github.com/biolab/orange3-associate/issues/4

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667272/orange-data-mining-version-3-3-python-association-rules